# "Dear All" difference between post and edit

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, edits

I was just out and about looking for posts to help me secure the timelord hat and I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160784/android-bluetooth-encryption-technique)

If you notice at the first of the question it says `Dear All`.

[image]

If however, you click edit and look at the text the `Dear All` has vanished.

[image]

This feels like a remove salutation bug, or the reverse of that, edit being right, and the post being wrong.

EDIT:
@gunr2171 has since edited the post and the `Dear All` goes away.

Comment: probably not a bug.  The question was probably asked before the automatic filter for such titles, so when you tried to edit it, it was automatically removed.

Comment: Oh of course.  It was just too old for that particular filter to have taken effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each post has both a current revision (which is the Markdown text that was last saved) and an HTML-rendered body that reflects what our rendering system thought should be generated from the Markdown text the last time it was saved.

Normally, they match pretty closely. But they *can* become out of sync. Particularly when [a new system for stripping greetings is implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989) and then separately applied to existing posts.

As a result, you'll see this same oddity on a lot of very-old questions that haven't been touched in years.

Comment: My assumption was that the stripping took place on the rendering of the post rather than on the editing.

Comment: It takes place on submission, before rendering.